# Getting JSON_Parser_error when using Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax to Create multiple records using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest-api, connected-apps, canvas, ajax

I am trying to insert 2 records at a time using canvas client in a connected app, using REST API, code and response below:

```js
Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax('/services/data/v47.0/composite/sobjects',{
   "allOrNone" : false,
   client: Sfdc.canvas.oauth.client(), method: 'POST',
       "records" : [{
          "attributes" : {"type" : "Account"},
          "Name" : "example.com",
          "BillingCity" : "San Francisco"
       }, {
          "attributes" : {"type" : "Contact"},  
          "LastName" : "Johnson",
          "FirstName" : "Erica"
       }],
   success: function(data){console.log(data.payload)}
})
```

Getting an error - "The HTTP entity body is required, but this request has no entity body."

But I am able to insert 1 record at a time with the code below.

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax('/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/account/',{
       client: Sfdc.canvas.oauth.client(),
    method: 'POST', data: '{"Name" : "California"}',
    success: function(data){console.log(data.payload)}
})
```

Any recommendation? Tried other implementations as described in

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm

and

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the `data` attribute in your JS Code. Also you should be using the `/composite/tree/{sobject}` resource as well based on the JSON you were trying to send. Here is an example

```
var postData = {
"records" :[
  {
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount1",
    "phone" : "1111111111",
    "website" : "www.salesforce1.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
    "industry" : "Banking"
  },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount2",
    "phone" : "2222222222",
    "website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "250",
    "industry" : "Banking"
  }]
};

Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax('/services/data/v47.0/composite/tree/Account',{
   "allOrNone" : false,
    client: Sfdc.canvas.oauth.client(),
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
   success: function(data){console.log(data.payload)}
})
```

Comment: Thanks much Bryan for your quick response. Did a trick with json stringify on postData and the above code to solve it.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry forgot to add that in